# Can one user be assigned different permissions in different sections with Workbench Access?

Tags: 7, users, workbench

We are testing the [Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench) and [Workbench Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_access) modules. We have many different sections on our site which are each managed by a specific department. These sections are established using a Vocabulary and this vocabulary is what we have configured to establish access through Workbench Access.

We have two main roles (aside from administrator) *Author* and *Publisher*. In essence, the author has less power and the Publisher has more.

**Is it possible for User X to have *Publisher* permission on a node in one section and *Author* permissions on a node in a different section?**

I have tried the following:

1. Assigning User X to the *Publisher* and *Author* roles.
2. Assign all *Authors* to Section 1 in the **Roles** Configuration of Access.
3. Assign User X to Section 1a (See example taxonomy below) in the **Editors** Configuration of Access.

The reason we want this configuration is so that, moving forward to [Workbench Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation), a user can have access to move a node in Section 2 to publication (since they're in charge of it) and also be able to make edits for review on typos or inaccuracies for *any* Section N they might notice needs it.

---

Example Taxonomy:

- Section 1

  - Section 1a
  - Section 1b
- Section 2

  - Section 2a
  - Section 2b

Comment: Just so it's clear, I've looked through all the documentation I could find on Workbench Access and have watched many videos (on Drupalize.me) and have been unable to figure out whether this is possible. I would think it would be a straightforward enough feature, but perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: I have been able to find neither a solution, nor a workaround. While we will simply have to exclude this feature moving forward, I would truly appreciate anyone sharing their insight on this. I would still love to be able to make it happen in the future.